# Why are my queries interfering with the global post variable?

Tags: plugins, metabox

I am developing a plugin.  There are two CPTs: category and dish.  In my edit dish page, I try to get the values for the fields by using `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dish_price', true)`  The problem is that any function I use to get the ID of the dish that's being edited returns the ID of the last category that was retrieved in my category dropdown list. What am I doing wrong?

```
function meta_boxes(){
    /*Category meta boxes */
    remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'category', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('commentsdiv', 'category', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', 'category', 'core' );
    add_meta_box( 'description', 'Description', 'category_description_meta_box', 'category' );
    /* Dish meta boxes */
    remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'dish', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('commentsdiv', 'dish', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', 'dish', 'core' );
    add_meta_box( 'parent_id', 'Category', 'dish_category_metabox', 'dish' );
    add_meta_box( 'description', 'Description', 'dish_description_meta_box', 'dish' );
    add_meta_box('dish_price', 'Price', 'dish_price_meta_box', 'dish');
}

function category_description_meta_box(){
    global $post;
    //var_dump($post)
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="category_noncename" id="category_noncename" value="' .wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    echo '<textarea style="width: 100%;" rows="5" name="description" id="description">'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', true).'</textarea>';
}

function dish_description_meta_box(){
    global $post;
    //var_dump($post)
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="dish_noncename" id="dish_noncename" value="' .wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    echo '<textarea style="width: 100%;" rows="5" name="description" id="description">'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', true).'</textarea>';
}

function dish_price_meta_box(){
    global $post;
    echo '$<input type="text" name="dish_price" id="dish_price" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dish_price', true).'">';
}

function dish_category_metabox()
{
    global $post;
    $out = '<select name="parent_id">'.PHP_EOL;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'category',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $out .= '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'"';
            if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'parent_id', true) == get_the_ID()){
                $out .= ' SELECTED';
            }
            $out .= '>'.get_the_title().'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    $out .= '</select>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo $out;
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'meta_boxes');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$the_query->the_post();` is populating the global `$post` with each post in that loop. On front-end queries, you'd normally call `wp_reset_postdata()` after running a secondary query loop, but that doesn't work on the admin side.

Use [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) instead of `WP_Query`, and iterate over the results with a `foreach` loop-

```
$my_posts = get_posts( $args );
if( !empty( $my_posts ) ){
    foreach( $my_posts as $my_post ){
        echo $my_post->ID;
        echo get_the_title( $my_post );
    }
}
```